# Windows Phone Navigate Progress Indicator

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am currently having problem with my Windows Phone 7 app. I have two pages:
- First contains checkbox and button to navigate to next page
- Second contains some controls with data that take about 3 seconds to load

So basically what happens now if user presses a button on first screen, it takes 3 seconds to navigate to second screen. I would like to add ProgressIndicator during this navigation process, but it dissapears, so it looks like i need to await navigation to the page. Can someone propose a way how can i do it:

```
prog.IsVisible = true;
prog.IsIndeterminate = true;
SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, prog);
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't place the progress indicator on the page you are navigating from, but rather on the page you are navigating to. So override `OnNavigatedTo` in the destination page and show indicator there.

Also, what is the source of this slowness? Is the page heavy with controls? Are you loading something from storage/internet? You should do that asynchronously if you aren't already.

Comment: Thank you, so basically if on second page i add OnNavigatedTo i will get ProgressIndicator appear on first page ? 
I have listpicker from toolkit, when there were 60 items it worked correctly, when i have added more countries and now there are 232 items it takes time to load the page.

Comment: `ListPicker` shouldn't be that slow. And it won't appear on the first page, it will appear on the second page only.

Comment: After i added extra items and i press button to navigate to next screen it takes time to load. I am adding 'ItemSource' in code and it is string array.

Comment: I have also tried your method to add indicator on second page, but it does not even appear, as when i press button this first page is presented and than after 3 seconds second page is loaded.

Comment: Are you loading something heavy in your second page's constructor?